# How to fix a 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook Reference' error?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, reference, mailitem

Visual Studio (2015 Community) does not seem to be recognizing `Microsoft.Office.Core` or `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` as references.  A yellow triangle is showing up to the left of both references and because of this and the `Using` directive `'using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;'` is being flagged as unnecessary. Hence, I cannot call the `MailItem` class.

Any assistance would be appreciated!

(I'm a rookie, so I apologize if I'm stating something incorrectly)

I was initially using VS 2019 Community and was told that this could be the problem and that I should try VS 2015.  I went to VS 2015 Community but the issue still exists.

My code:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application;

-------------------

MailItem email = outlookApp.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
```

When I attempt to build my code then receive the following errors:

> CS0234 The type or namespace name 'Office' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>    - *I get this for each Using directive mentioned above*
>
> CS0246    The type or namespace name 'MailItem' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> CS0103    The name 'OlItemType' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 4):

I was able to find the solution for this.  I did not have the proper Microsoft packages added to the solution.  I opened NuGet (tools > NuGet Package Manager > Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...) and searched for the proper assemblies and then added them to the Solution.

This resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this from right clicking add reference,
1. In Solution Explorer, right-click your project's name and then click Add Reference. The 
   Add Reference dialog box appears.
2. On the Assemblies page, select Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word in the Component Name list, 
   and then hold down the CTRL key and select Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel. ...
3. Click OK.
I think it will works for you..

Comment: When I attempt to add the references the Microsoft.Office options are not in the list on the Assemblies page.  Other Microsoft options are available but none of the .Office options are there.